# Export Data from Excel to Text File

Tags: vba, excel

i need help plz

I have a excel file and I want to export all data from it to a text file.

This the source code:

---

```
Sub ExceltoText()

    Dim FileName, sLine, Deliminator, x, y, z As String
    Dim LastCol, LastRow, FileNumber As Integer


    FileName = "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\App vba\ExcToTxt.txt"

    Deliminator = "|"
    x = "$|0|Les Données de SALARIES"
    y = "=|0|Les Données de SALARIES"
    z = "=|1|SALARIES|"

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    FileNumber = FreeFile

    Open FileName For Output As FileNumber

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            If j = LastCol Then
                sLine = z & sLine & Cells(i, j).Value
            Else
                sLine = sLine & Cells(i, j).Value & Deliminator
            End If
        Next j
        If i = 1 Then i = 2
        Print #FileNumber, sLine
        sLine = ""
    Next i
    Close #FileNumber
    MsgBox "File generated"
End Sub
```

---

In the result I got this text file in that format:

---

```
=|1|SALARIES|PSA_etablissement|PSA_SALARIE|

=|1|SALARIES|001|10635|

=|1|SALARIES|001|10637|
```

But I want my text file to be like that:

---

```
$=|1|SALARIES|PSA_etablissement|PSA_SALARIE|

=|1|SALARIES|001|10635|

=|1|SALARIES|001|10637|
```

and I want to add those lines in the beginning of the text file:

---

```
$|0|Les Données de SALARIES

=|0|Les Données de SALARIES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this routine:

Added the two lines outside your for loop.

Also '&' and '=' is the only difference in that line, so take it as a variable without those symbols.

Sub ExceltoText()

```
Dim FileName As String, sLine As String, Deliminator As String
Dim x As String, y As String, z As String
Dim LastCol As Integer, LastRow As Integer, FileNumber As Integer

FileName = "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\App vba\ExcToTxt.txt"
Deliminator = "|"
x = "$=|1|SALARIES|PSA_etablissement|PSA_SALARIE|"
y = "|0|Les Données de SALARIES"
z = "=|1|SALARIES|"

LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

FileNumber = FreeFile

Open FileName For Output As FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, "$" & y
Print #FileNumber, "=" & y
Print #FileNumber, x

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If j = LastCol Then
            sLine = z & sLine & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
            sLine = sLine & Cells(i, j).Value & Deliminator
        End If
    Next j
    Print #FileNumber, sLine
    sLine = ""
Next i
Close #FileNumber
MsgBox "File generated"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

To add the lines at the beginning of the file, just before the FOR loop add:

```
Print #FileNumber, x
Print #FileNumber, y
```

To put that dollar sign before only the first line while iterating change:

```
If i = 1 Then i = 2
Print #FileNumber, sLine
sLine = ""
```

To:

```
If i = 1 Then 
   i = 2
   Print #FileNumber, "$" & sLine
Else
   Print #FileNumber, sLine
End If
sLine = ""
```